# How to export a Plain with 2 image textures on each side as a glb file

Tags: texturing, materials, export

Hey there a blender noob here! I have a model of a box I made for a project. The object is a simple cube and using a mixture and geometry node I have applied 2 different image textures on each side of every single face (Each face has a different image texture on the front and back) .

The problem comes when I try to export the box as a glb file. The file always comes out with only one of the image textures applied. How can I fix that.

Cheers!